# Why does this p.stdin.write is not working?

Tags: python, subprocess

[Thanks! Because of the command, I was able to bypass that step, but the actual problem is this step, there is no command given in the documentation for this step.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mDLla.png)
[1][I have added an example of how the menu option looks like, for this say I want to select force field number 4, so, when I do `subprocess.call[path,4]` it will give me an error as the path file will be called afresh and the menu options will disappear.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/su6Xf.png)
The file is being called using this -

```
p = subprocess.Popen(path, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, shell = False, universal_newlines=True)
```

But when I try to write on the file using p.stdin.write, it does not write anything.

```
p.stdin.write("pdb2gmx""-f"+ pname +"-o""processed.gro""-water"+ water_model +"-ff"+ force_field)
```

pname, water_model, force_field are global variables. Nothing happens when I want the p.stdin.write to write this command on the path file.

**Edit -
I tried using subprocess.check_call() instead of p.stdin.write, but with subprocess.check_call() for every step a new process is created and the path file is called again, so the previous process gets killed and a new process starts. I don't want that.**

Comment: What "file is being called"? What's in `path`? What you're trying to write into that process's stdin looks like a command line, which sound suspect. (And is missing a newline.)

Comment: Yes, I am trying to call a command line tool.

Answer (score 0):

If `pdb2gmx` is actually the name of the tool you want to call, you'll want e.g.

```
import subprocess

subprocess.call(
    [
        "pdb2gmx",
        "-f",
        pname,
        "-o",
        "processed.gro",
        "-water",
        water_model,
        "-ff",
        force_field,
    ],
    check=True,
)
```

instead of starting a process and writing that command line to its standard input.

Comment: Yes, actually, I tried this and this works fine. But say for the next step I want this subprocess to be alive but when I try writing the command for the next step the subprocess will again call the path file, so the first process gets killed. Hope I was able to explain it.

Comment: @MilindChauhan why not just call `subprocess.call(['pdb2gmx', ...])` multiple times?

Comment: Yes, I did think of that, but at one step I get a menu option from which I need to choose one, so say for example, out of 14 options displayed I want to choose number 13, so when I say - **subprocess.call([path,13])**, it doesn't work because of this **subprocess** as the path file is called again and the menu options vanish, so it says 13 as an invalid input. I hope I was able to explain it. @bereal

Comment: @MilindChauhan Please add an example _into the original question_ of what the menu looks like when you run the tool interactively.

Comment: @MilindChauhan [According to the tool's documentation](https://manual.gromacs.org/documentation/current/onlinehelp/gmx-pdb2gmx.html) you should be able to pass `-ff <string>: Force field, interactive by default.` so you don't need to try to pass in input interactively.

Comment: @AKX thanks for the help! Please check, I have attached another image.

Comment: There is also a `-nointer` flag that should disable all of those interactive questions...

Comment: Anyway if you can't help but interact with the software, please see https://pexpect.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

Comment: `-nointer`? where? @AKX

Comment: In the parameters, like `-ff ...`.

Comment: I'll check that, thanks!!